# Eliminating of variable with static storage duration

Tags: c++, storage-duration

I came across the following rule (3.7.1/2 N3797):

> If a variable with static storage duration has initialization or a
>   destructor with side effects, it shall not be eliminated even if it
>   appears to be unused, except that a class object or its copy/move may
>   be eliminated as specified in 12.8.

Is it true that, if we declare a variable with static storage duration, having constructor or destructor with side-effect, then the memory will allocate for that variable even if it is unused?

In particular, I'm trying to experiment with the following code:

```
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout;

struct data_member
{
    data_member(){ cout << "data_member\n"; }
    ~data_member(){ cout << "~data_member\n"; }
};

struct Y
{
    static data_member m;
    Y(){ cout << "Y\n"; }
    ~Y(){ cout << "~Y\n"; }
};

Y y;


int main()
{
}
```

[IdeOne](http://ideone.com/maKW46)

Why does data_member object not constructed in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's what the standard says, so ... yes.

As always, there's the as-if rule, allowing a compiler to do practically anything, as long as the net effect is the same. I could imagine that if the class is huge data-wise, but the constructor and destructor (and anybody else) do not access that data, the compiler could just call the constructor and destructor in the proper order, without leaving space for the unused data.

---

As for your example, you're *declaring* `Y::m`, but you never *define* it. So it doesn't exist. If you tried to access it, you'd get a linker error.

Comment: So why does data member not constructed in the http://ideone.com/maKW46 ? Both constructor and destructor contain side-effect.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv That's a data member, not a variable. And BTW, it might be a good idea to add that code example to your question. The way your question is phrased now, it almost looks like you're trying to troll/trick someone.

Comment: Actually, A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a _non-static data member_ or of an object. Thanks! But why   does data member does not constructed in the example? If I remove static modifier it will construct successfully.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv You're right, it *is* a variable. My bad. But note that as any other static data member, its in-class declaration is just a declaration. You have to define it as well. If you tried to use it now, you'd get a linker error. I've edited that into the answer as well.

Comment: Might I don't understand you, but I don't recieve linker error. http://ideone.com/2eFE0y

Comment: @DmitryFucintv But you could, and you would if `data_member` contained any data you accessed: http://ideone.com/NcfJ7L